# Does Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1 support this scenario?

Tags: asp.net, synchronization

Does Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1 support this scenario?

I'm using ASP.NET 3.5 and Sql Server 2008.

My scenario is that I want to sync data between two tables of Sql Server 2008 databases in two remote distributed places.

1) I totally own the two database server with remote desktop rights.

2) The database A has a table CustomerA with the column A_Id, A_UserId, A_Mobile,
   and database B has a table CustomerB with the column B_Id, B_UserId, B_Mobile.

I want to sync the data from CustomerA to CustomerB with the columns A_UserId -> B_UserId and A_Mobile -> B_Mobile.

3) I want to encrypt the data in C# from A_Mobile and store it in B_Mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sync selected columns by using SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder in 2.1.

```
DbSyncTableDescription tableDescription = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable(tableName, Collection<Columns>, serverConnection);
```

For the second parameter, you can give the Columns to include in Scope for that table.

Not sure of Encryption though. You can try using various events on Provider to achieve this. I haven't tried it personally.